# I have a reboot error for installing nvidia-driver

Tags: linux, nvidia

I've installed nvidia-driver-535, and then reboot my ubuntu 22.04.

But I have an error like this:

```bash
[2172.336996] systemd-shutdown [1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[2172.339443] systemd-shutdown [1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[2172.342697] systemd-journald [319]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[2352.376330] [50442]: Remounting '/' read-only in with options 'errors=remount-ro'.
[2352.376381] [50442]: Failed to remount '/' read-only: Device or resource busy
[2352.376592] systemd-shutdown [1]: Not all file systems unmounted, 1 left.
[2352.376628] systemd-shutdown [1]: Cannot finalize remaining file systems, continuing. [1]: Failed to finalize file systems, ignoring.
[2352.396946] systemd-shutdown systemd-shutdown [1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[2352.399521] systemd-shutdown [1]: Rebooting.
```

It doesn't end... how can I fix this?

I want to reboot my linux system.

Comment: This isn't related to programming in any way; therefore rather belongs to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). For example: https://askubuntu.com/a/707123